# How do I remove event listeners when switching route in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to remove event listeners when switchin route in react?
My routers switch looks like this:

```
<Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Menu setLang={setLang} />}></Route>
            <Route path="/gallery">
              <Gallery />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/about">
              <About />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/contact">
              <Contact />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
```

And in my Menu component I have a useEffect that runs my function which manages my navbar to be shorter or longer and puts navbar items in dropdown if there is no space.

```
useEffect(() => {
    manageCategoriesNav();
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => manageCategoriesNav());
    window.removeEventListener('resize', () => manageCategoriesNav());
  }, [state.lang]);
```

The thing is that this navbar is only in my Menu component, so when i switch to diffrent route and resize window I get error because my function manageCategoriesNav() uses querySelector that catches items which are only in Menu component. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, effects can return a callback for this exact use case !

You can wrap your `removeEventListener` in a function call like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    manageCategoriesNav();
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => manageCategoriesNav());
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', () => manageCategoriesNav());
  }, [state.lang]);
```

Then react will call the callback, and as such remove the event when the function is called.

Also, you don't actually need to create a callback since `manageCategoriesNav` is already a function, so you can just write:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    manageCategoriesNav();
    window.addEventListener('resize', manageCategoriesNav);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', manageCategoriesNav);
  }, [state.lang]);
```

I'm not 100% sure that `state.lang` is the right input for your `useEffect` either !

> Read more about it in the official react documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :( Maybe becasue I didn't say that my useEffect is in Menu component. Also state.lang is there because I want to run my function whenever I change language in my state.

Comment: then your problem is more due too how `manageCategoriesNav` is implemented, we can't really help you without more code examples.

Answer (score 0):

use the `return` keyword to remove the event. The method is called when the component is unmounting, so when you change route.

```
useEffect(() => {
    manageCategoriesNav();
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => manageCategoriesNav());
    return () =>  window.removeEventListener('resize', () => manageCategoriesNav());
  }, [state.lang]);
```